# Laravel, how to insert into pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have 3 tables:

- Doctors (id, name)
- Schedules (id, day)
- Doctor_schedule (id, doctor_id, shcedule_id, t_start, t_end)

My question is how do I insert into Doctor_schedule table?
I have form something like this:
[enter image description here][1]
this is the doctor_schedule and i want to add doctor_shcedule like this:
[enter image description here][2]

Thanks for the answer..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l2Rx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZMqm.png

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the relation in the Doctor model like this:

```
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Schedule::class)->withPivot('t_start', 't_end');
}
```

And in your Schedule model as well:

```
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Doctor::class)->withPivot('t_start', 't_end');
}
```

Then, in your controller you can insert records like this:

```
$doctor->schedules()->attach($scheduleId, ['t_start' => $tStart, 't_end' => $tEnd]);
```

Or you can do it the other way around as wall:

```
$schedule->doctors()->attach($doctorId, ['t_start' => $tStart, 't_end' => $tEnd]);
```

Comment: This is my code: